# Convert Json string to DataTable

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, json.net

I am trying to Convert Json to DataTable. I found success when converting jsonArray to DataTable. However when converting a json string(below):

```
var r = {'ASSOCIATION_ID':61.0,'DESCRIPTION':'fssESTf64 - false','ACTIVE':true,'MODEL_TYPE':'0','SEARCH_TYPE':'false','CREATED_BY':'1090323','CREATED_DATE':'2015-09-17T14:41:20','LAST_UPDATED_BY':'1090323','LAST_UPDATED_DATE':'2016-02-26T15:55:54'}
```

I get an error as {"Unexpected JSON token when reading DataTable. Expected StartArray, got StartObject. Path '', line 1, position 1."}

My code is simple:

```
DataTable a = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(r);
```

Please assist.

Comment: "Expected StartArray" implies that the function is expecting an array of objects as opposed to a single object.

Comment: it seems like you have access to the data that you are returning. why don't you just serialize a DataTable that contains this data?

Comment: A `DataTable` serializes as an array of objects containing key/value pairs, as is shown here: [Serialize a DataSet](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeDataSet.htm).  Your JSON is a single object.  What do you want - a `DataTable` with one row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your root [JSON](http://json.org/) container is an object (an unordered collection of comma-separated key/value pairs surrounded by braces - `{` and `}`).  Json.NET serializes a `DataTable` as an *array* of objects (an ordered collection of comma-separated tokens surrounded by square brackets `[` and `]`), with one array entry for each row, as is shown in [Serialize a DataSet](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeDataSet.htm).  I.e. the following can be deserialized as a data table:

```
[
  {
    "ASSOCIATION_ID": 61.0,
    "DESCRIPTION": "fssESTf64 - false",
    "ACTIVE": true,
    "MODEL_TYPE": "0",
    "SEARCH_TYPE": "false",
    "CREATED_BY": "1090323",
    "CREATED_DATE": "2015-09-17T14:41:20",
    "LAST_UPDATED_BY": "1090323",
    "LAST_UPDATED_DATE": "2016-02-26T15:55:54"
  }
]
```

Thus your JSON cannot be mapped automatically to a `DataTable` by Json.NET.

If you want, you could deserialize your JSON object as a `DataTable` with one row.  To do that, load it into an intermediate [`JToken`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken.htm), check if it's an object instead of an array, and if so, wrap it in an array, then deserialize:

```
var token = JToken.Parse(r);

if (token.Type == JTokenType.Object)
    token = new JArray(token);

var a = token.ToObject<DataTable>();
```

Comment: Thanks and I could add "[" and "]" to front and rear and convert it using JArray itself, correct?

Comment: I suppose you could even do `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>("[" + r + "]");` but it feels safer to check to see whether `r` is an array or object first rather than assuming it is not an array.

Comment: Yeah, I am doing that by checking. One more favor, Is there a way to parse json which contains special characters like ?, #,... Please assist.

Comment: I have posted a separate question for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36550246/parse-json-with-special-characters-like-etc Please assist.